# Can't place PlotLabels with PlotLayout->"Row"

Tags: plotting, version-12

When I try to plot a set of graphs using `ListPlot` with `PlotLayout->{"Row", 4}`, and then try to label the plots using `PlotLabels`, the label appears above and the plot range is increased to accommodate the label. I try to use the `PlotLabels -> Placed[labels, Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]`, but this produces a single label for the first plot that is "`Placed[labels, Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]`". Does anyone know whether this is a bug? Is there a workaround?

```
d = Table[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}], 8];
ListPlot[d, PlotLayout -> {"Row", 4}, PlotLabels -> Range[10]]
```

[image]

However, this gives an unexpected result:

```
ListPlot[d, PlotLayout -> {"Row", 4}, PlotLabels -> Placed[Range[10], Scaled[{.8, .8}]]]
```

[image]

I would like to be able to use `Placed` to move the labels within the plots.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange! In general, your question looks good, but please consider adding _specific_ code to reproduce your issue to your question - some code any person can run that will display your problem. This is called a Minimum Working Example, or MWE, and will greatly help your chances of getting a useful answer! It might also be useful to add a screenshot of your issue, and a description of what you were expecting to happen.

Comment: I have added code and screenshots of what I think you are describing to your question - I hope that's correct! It does seem like odd behaviour.

Comment: @Carl Lange: Thanks for adding an example and for verifying this odd "feature".

Comment: No problem, happy to help. It seems like the labels are done using `Inset` when you use this form, and that may be part of the problem (you can see this using `InputForm` of the plots). I don't really know what to do with this, unfortunately!